# react-native: how to load more items while user scrolling FlatList

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-native-flatlist

I want to load the list of products from local API work with pages and I want to load new products while the user is scrolling, the problem is when I want to push the new product to the list of products using setProduct `const [products, setProducts] = useState<ProductModel[]>([]);`

this is the function loading products:

```
const getProductList = async () => {
    const token: string | null = await localStorage.getValue("token");

    console.log("page:", currentPage);
    if (currentPage >= maxNumberOfPages - 1) {
      setLoading(true);
      getAllProducts(token!, currentPage)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(
            "res",
            res.data.numberOfElements,
            "totalPages: ",
            res.data.totalPages
          );
          if (products.length === 0) {
            setProducts(res.data.content);
            setCurrentPage(1);
            setMaxNumberOfPages(res.data.totalPages);
            setLoading(false);
          }
          if (products!.length > 0 && res.data.numberOfElements > 0) {
            setProducts([...products, res.data.content]); <== error happened here
            setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
            setLoading(false);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("get products error:", error);
        });
    }
  };
```

flat list component:

```
 {products.length !== 0 ? (
        <FlatList
          data={products}
          renderItem={renderPrices}
          numColumns={1}
          // keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          ListFooterComponent={() =>
            loading ? (
              <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Spinner size="giant" />
              </View>
            ) : null
          }
          nestedScrollEnabled={true}
          onEndReached={() => getProductList()}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        />
      ) : (
        <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Spinner size="giant" />
        </View>
      )}Ï
```

this error happens when I tried to `setProducts([...products, res.data.content]);`  screenshot of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
setProducts([...products, ...res.data.content])
```

make sure you're also spreading the 2nd array.